# Loading multiple shapefiles with different names, from +1000 subfolders

Tags: arcpy, walk

I'm looking to add a large number of point files into an .mxd from a huge group of multi-layer folders. The script from [Loading multiple shapefiles from +1000 subfolders](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/179502) worked with some tweaks, but doesn't return anything presumably since all of the files have different names after the prefix (i.e. Subject Baltimore / Subject Aberdeen / Subject Rockville etc).

Is there a way to add something to tell the script to look at just the first part of the shapefile's label? here is the code I'm using:

```
import os

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

workspace = "T:\\GIS\\Special Projects\\ESRI UC MAP 2017\\Maryland"    #place the path to your data inside the quote marks, remembering to use forward slashes
feature_classes = []

walk = arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, datatype="FeatureClass", type="Point")

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
    for filename in filenames:
        feature_classes.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))

for dataset in feature_classes:
    dataset = dataset.upper()
    if "Subject" in dataset:
        add_layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(dataset)
        arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, add_layer)
```

Comment: Have you tried to use all caps for the string "Subject"? That is, "SUBJECT"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the string in your `if` statement needs to be capitalized. The `upper()` method returns a copy of the string where all case-based characters are uppercased. In order to match the characters in `dataset` with those in your string, they may need to be capitalized. See string in `if` statement below.

```
import os

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

workspace = "T:\\GIS\\Special Projects\\ESRI UC MAP 2017\\Maryland"    #place the path to your data inside the quote marks, remembering to use forward slashes
feature_classes = []

walk = arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, datatype="FeatureClass", type="Point")

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:
    for filename in filenames:
        feature_classes.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))

for dataset in feature_classes:
    dataset = dataset.upper()
    if "SUBJECT" in dataset:
        add_layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(dataset)
        arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, add_layer)
```

Comment: YES! That totally worked! Thank you! None of the shapefile labels are capped so I wasn't sure about that one....if we got rid of that line would it still work? I'm a super beginner with Python so forgive my ignorance.

Comment: Great! A good way to show thanks is to mark an answer as accepted. Keep at it.

Comment: My understanding is that the upper() method is used to deal with issues of discrepancies in capitalization. You should try to see what happens when that line is absent.

Comment: Awesome - thanks for the tips - First time posting here :) - I'll try it with out, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Basic but important question: Are you running this python script within ArcMap? Using arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(“CURRENT”) requires to be run within the MXD. It can't be run "outside" of MXD environment.

I agree with reevesii's comment. Try making all caps on “”subject” so it looks like this:

if “SUBJECT” in dataset:

The line Before says the dataset is put into all caps by dataset.upper()  . Please note that all layers you add to MXD this way will in caps.

Comment: YES! That totally worked! I am running it through ArcMap only. Thank you!